# How do you put an image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a game that would randomly pick a photo and let that photo replace the previous photo but I don't know how to code it in javascript.

This is what I've tried but it's not working.

This is the javascript.

```
var trash = [["recycle1.png", "recycle2.png","recycle3.png"],["bio1.png","bio2.png","bio3.png"],["nonbio1.png", "nonbio2.png", "nonbio3.png"]];

function game ()
    {var trashKind = trash[Math.floor(Math.random()*trash.length)][Math.floor(Math.random()*trash.length)];
    document.getElementById("trash").src = "../images/" + trashKind;};

game ();
```

This is the html.

```
<div><img id="trash" src="../images/recycle2.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the html is:

```
<img src="random-picture.jpg" alt="random-picture" id="theImage">
```

So you need to do something like that:

```
const arr = ["picture.jpg" , "picture2.jpg" , "picture3.jpg"];
const arrLength = arr.length;
const num = Math.floor( (Math.random())*arrLength );
document.getElementById("theImg").src = `/images/lol/${arr[num]}`;
```

pay attention to the ``
you can continue from here easily

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a 2D array,you can create like an 1D array,since it will affect the index.

```
var trash = ["recycle1.png", "recycle2.png","recycle3.png","bio1.png","bio2.png","bio3.png","nonbio1.png", "nonbio2.png", "nonbio3.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only displaying one image at the same time, and the image HTML tag is already in your DOM, then you only need to code a bit of JavaScript to handle the source change of that image tag.

### Use an interval to change the image every certain time

If your image HTML tag has an id attribute, you can reference that image in JavaScript:

```html
<div>
  <img id="image" src="noimageyet" alt="noimageyet">
</div>
```

And in your JavaScript, define an array of the pictures you want to use, the code adjusts to the size of the array, so no matter how many images you add to your array, the code will always randomize the image from the array.

#### JavaScript:

```
var gameImage = document.querySelector("#image"),
    images = ["recycle1.png", "recycle2.png","recycle3.png","bio1.png","bio2.png","bio3.png","nonbio1.png", "nonbio2.png", "nonbio3.png"];
function grn(min, max) {
    return parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
function game(){
  let newImage = images[grn(0,images.length)];
  gameImage.src = newImage;
  gameImage.alt = newImage;
}
setInterval(game,1000);
```

And that should do the trick for you. You can view it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k3llydev/gr2nmz5c/).